# How to download a file from a website to a user's iCloud

Tags: ios, download, file-sharing

I have an iOS app that downloads data files from webpages. Often a user will come across the webpage, but will not yet have the app. Rather than get them to download the app and then re-find the webpage within the app, I would like to download the data file, then have the app pick that up when it is installed. From what I can gather, I need to put that file in the iCloud. But when I try to download the file with Safari, it tells me it cannot download the file. If I use Chrome, it wants me to use GoogleDrive to save the file. Is there a way a webpage can save a file to iCloud? Or is there some other way to tell the app what file to download when it has been installed?

Comment: check solution here with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456210/icloud-integration-for-uploading-and-downloading-files)

Comment: Thanks, but that does not tell me how a webpage can download a file to a users iCloud. I can do this within my app. But I want the file downloaded by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just heard the official word from Apple. There is NO way to copy/transfer/download a file (image or otherwise) from an internet site to the user's iCloud.

By experimentation I have discovered that Safari WILL download some file types (eg jpegs) from a webpage, other file types will give the error mentioned in the question, but NO files will be placed in the iCloud. And so no files will be available to my app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in ios app development,but i am trying to answer this .please use following code:

```
 - (void)download:(NSURL *)url
{
    dispatch_queue_t q_default;
    q_default = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(q_default, ^{

        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:url error:&error];
        if (!success)
        {
            // failed to download
        }
        else
        {
            NSDictionary *attrs = [url resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey] error:&error];
            if (attrs != nil)
            {
                if ([[attrs objectForKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey] boolValue])
                {
                    // already downloaded
                }
                else
                {
                    NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
                    [query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > 0", NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey]];
                    [query setSearchScopes:@[url]]; // scope the search only on this item

                    [query setValueListAttributes:@[NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey, NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey]];

                    _fileDownloadMonitorQuery = query;

                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                             selector:@selector(liveUpdate:)
                                                                 name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification
                                                               object:query];

                    [self.fileDownloadMonitorQuery startQuery];
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

- (void)liveUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSMetadataQuery *query = [notification object];

    if (query != self.fileDownloadMonitorQuery)
        return; // it's not our query

    if ([self.fileDownloadMonitorQuery resultCount] == 0)
        return; // no items found

    NSMetadataItem *item = [self.fileDownloadMonitorQuery resultAtIndex:0];
    double progress = [[item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey] doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"download progress = %f", progress);

    // report download progress somehow..

    if ([[item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey] boolValue])
    {
        // finished downloading, stop the query
        [query stopQuery];
        _fileDownloadMonitorQuery = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the webpage to download the file to iCloud. Perhaps I should not have mentioned the app at all. I don't need help with the app discovering the file in iCloud. I just need to get the file onto (into?) the iCloud before my app is installed. If only there was some kind of pass-through parameter that you could send via the app store.